# Can I pass parameters to Scala REPL using :load?

Tags: scala

From the Scala REPL I am running a program thus:

```
:load foo.scala
```

I want to pass foo a parameter so I try:

```
:load foo.scala 1.0
```

which gives:

```
usage: :load -v file
```

Is there any way of running a program from the REPL with parameters like this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single source file, I would recommend using the :paste command with which you can copy the whole source file into the REPL and then do a ctrl + c to exit the paste mode.

You could then call your program from the REPL by passing in the parameters that you need!